# Prove that $|x|\neq0$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove that $\forall x\in \Re,|x|\neq0$.

I know I need to prove this by contradiction by indicating $\exists 0 \in \Bbb R $ such that $|0|=0$.

Comment: Isn't $0 \in \Bbb R$?

Comment: yes. 0 is a real number.

Comment: So, since $0\in\Bbb R$, what is $|0|$?

Comment: Well, since $|0| = 0$, it seems to me the proposition is false, and trying to prove it is doomed to fail.

Comment: I guess that is the reason why I need to prove by contradition.

Comment: You are trying to use a proof by contradiction? No, you can not. Rather, you have to disprove it by  providing a counter example.

Comment: "I guess that is the reason why I need to prove by contradition."  No.  If something is false (as this is) it is false.  You can't prove it with *any* method, contradiction or direct.  This statement is utterly false.  A cuter example (|0|=0) ***dis***proves it.  But it can NOT be proven by any method.

Answer (score 2):

$$\forall x\in\mathbb R, |x|\ne0\implies |0|\ne0,$$ a contradiction, as by definition of the absolute value, $0\ge0\implies|0|=0$.